# Is there any solution for this Error running Gradle problem?

Tags: flutter

When I try to run any of my flutters project I face this issue
console:

Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\User\Downloads\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Configure project :app

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 36

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.

FlutterPlugin

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command: C:\Users\User\Downloads\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: Could you share your project on github? It not easy to identify error with only error messages.

Comment: I had tried to run simple flutter build in basic app but when I run this I see this in the output console. I think it's a flutter bug . I am using latest flutter SDK and the latest version of android studio.